# Get Method status Issue

Tags: api, get, status

I am testing API'S. In which I use GET method to check responses. I Perform Searching by using ID.I enter invalid value Like I search ID=30 but there is no record of ID=30 But still it will show 200 Status. But it should be show us 204 Status. Is it wrong or Right or why they are showing 200 status if there is no data?

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong ideally the HttpStatus code should be in sync with the response of the API's.

e.g.

**200 Ok :** Successful request with data

**204 No Content :** Successful request with No data and so on..

They need to put a check of empty data and set **`HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT (204)`** before sending the response back to client otherwise it will show **`HttpStatus.OK (200)`** by default.

***They can put some check like this:***

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(result, result==null ? HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT : HttpStatus.OK);
```